# non-numeric argument error while running FFT on a matrix

Tags: r, fft

I read eachline of a csv file and save the first element of each line in a list, then I want to run FFT on this list, but I get this error:

```
Error in fft(x) : non-numeric argument
```

in my Example hier I read 4 rows:

```
 con<-file("C:\\bla\\test.csv","r")
    datalist<-list()
    m<-list()
    for(i in 1:4)
    {

  line<-readLines(con,n=1,warn=FALSE)
  m<-list(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(line,split=","))))
  datalist<-c(datalist,sapply(m,"[[",1))
}

datalist
close(con)
fftfun<- function(x) {fft(x)}
fft_amplitude <- function(x) {sqrt((Re(fft(x)))^2+(Im(fft(x)))^2)}  }
apply(as.matrix(datalist),2,FUN=fftfun)
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

**EDIT**
My rows in csv file:

```
12,85,365,145,23
13,84,364,144,21
14,86,366,143,24
15,83,363,146,22
16,85,365,145,23
17,80,361,142,21
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you without having access to at least a sample of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems overly complicated. Why don't you just do something like this :

```
df <- read.csv("test.csv", header=FALSE)
x <- df[,1]
fft(x)
```

Or, if you really want to read line by line :

```
con <- file("test.csv","r")
data <- NULL
for (i in 1:4) {
    line<-readLines(con,n=1,warn=FALSE)
    data <- c(data, as.numeric(strsplit(line,split=",")[[1]][1]))
}
close(con)
fft(data)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I want to read line by line ( I have a csv file with 1500 rows and 7500 columns). I want only to test it with this sample

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your real question is: what happened to make apparently numeric data become non-numeric?   Rather than slogging through the incredible number of type coercions in your code (csv to matrix to list to other list to as.matrix),  I'm going to recommend you start by just plain reading one file into `R` and checking the `typeof` and `class` of each column.  If anything turns out to be a `factor` rather than `numeric` , you may need to add the argument colClasses='character' .
If the data as read are numeric, then you're fouling it up in your subsequent conversions.  Try simplifying the code as much as possible.